# Hover over font-awsome icons

Tags: html, css

So im trying to target the font-awsome icons and put a hover effect on them, i want them to change the color and also become a little bigger when hover over them. But no mather how i try to target the class i wont work.

```css
.i:hover {
color: red;
font-size: 20px;

}


.fab fa-facebook-square:hover {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;    

}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=509317209&ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ponteeee/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ponteeee/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not a class, it is an element. Therefore you should drop the `.` at the beginning

```
i:hover {
   color: red;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

Also, since two classes are there in the second selector, you need to drop the white space in between like this,

```
.fab.fa-facebook-square:hover {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

If you add a space in-between, it gives the idea that `fa-facebook-square` is a child of `fab`

And You don't need both rules, so you can remove one of them

Head over to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp to learn more about CSS selectors.

Also, to make the transitions more smooth, you can add a small transition,

```
i {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct you selectors:

- `i` is a html element so no need a dot `.`
- You have to use a dot `.` with class name and remove the spaces as the classes belong to same element (space make a relation between parent -> child element)

```css
i:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* This CSS is useless and can be removed 
.fab.fa-facebook-square:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=509317209&ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ponteeee/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ponteeee/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part A)**

> `i` selector is'nt class,so no need `.`; remove it like this:

```
i:hover { color: red; font-size: 20px; }
```

**Part B)**

> 1) you miss `.` in `fa-facebook-square` selector
>
> 2) remove space between `.fab` and `.fa-facebook-square` selector,because they refer to the same element,change like this:

```
.fab.fa-facebook-square:hover {
```

**Note:** if you want active `hover` pesudo on all `i`s,use of PartA and remove PartB.but if you want active `hover` pesudo just on `.fa-facebook-square`, remove PartA and use PartB.

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereWith this code you can hover on all three icon fonts.

```css
.fab.fa-facebook-square:hover, 
.fab.fa-twitter-square:hover,
.fab.fa-instagram:hover{
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*Or giving them seperate color for each icon-font


/*Blue color for Instagram*/
.fab.fa-facebook-square:hover{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*LightBlue color for Instagram*/ 
.fab.fa-twitter-square:hover{
  color: #ADD8E6; 
  font-size: 20px;
}

 
/*Instagram Logo Dark Blue*/
.fab.fa-instagram:hover{
  color:#125688;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors must correctly specify the elements which you intend to target.

> **CSS selectors** define the elements to which a set of CSS rules apply.
>   Ref: [CSS selectors - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

---

### Behaviour:

- **Selectors:** `.i:hover`
- **Targeting elements:** with class of "i", e.g: `class="i"`
- **Problem:** no element with class `.i` can be found
- **Solution:** use the ***Type Selector*** to target the *type* of element,
  e.g: `i`

### Demonstration:

***[Type Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)***

- Selects all elements that match the given node name.
- **Syntax:** *`eltname`*
- **Example:** `i` will match any `<i>` element.

### Example:

```
/* to apply rule to all intended elements, specify the type of selector*/
i:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```css
* {
  transition: .7s;
}

/* to apply rule to all intended elements, specify the type of selector*/
i:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<h3>To rectify the issue:</h3>
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fab fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></li>
</ul>
```

---

### Behaviour:

- **Selectors:** `.fab fa-facebook-square:hover`
- **Targeting elements:** containing elements, with class of "fab", that have nested elements (`fa-facebook-square`), e.g:
- **Problem:** **(1)** no containing (parent) element with class `.fab` can be found, with specified nested (child) element, **(2)** specified nested child element, by the name of `fa-facebook-square`, does not exist and is not a valid `html` element (*clearly intended to reference an element with the specified `class` attribute instead*).
- **Solution:** use the ***Class selector*** to target the *class* of the element,
  e.g: `.fab`, or `.fa`, etc.

### Demonstration:

***[Class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)***

- Selects all elements that have the given *class* attribute.
- **Syntax:** *`.classname`*
- **Example:** `.fab` will match any element that has a class of "index".

### Example:

```
/* to apply rule to all intended elements, specify the recurring class selector*/
.fab:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```css
* {
  transition: .7s;
}

/* to apply rule to all intended elements, specify the recurring class selector*/
.fab:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<h3>To rectify the issue:</h3>
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fab fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></li>
</ul>
```